# Change selected directory at startup of docker container

Tags: docker

Is it possible to save the selected directory in docker before exiting the container?

As a default, docker does not remember the selected directory before it exits.
In the example below, I changed the directory inside docker to home.

Example:

```
> docker exec -it loving_mccarthy /bin/bash
root@6bd70522dd17:/# cd /home
root@6bd70522dd17:/home# exit
exit

> docker exec -it loving_mccarthy /bin/bash
/#
```

Comment: When you `docker run` a container, it doesn't remember _anything_ when it exits.  If you need to make persistent changes like this typically you'd want to make them in the image's Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this behavior by setting up a bash function, which you can configure to run on terminal exit, that writes the current working directory to the .bashrc file, which you can then use the second time you run a bash terminal in the container with `cd -`.

Here's a full example:

Start the container:

```
$ docker run -it --name=example -d ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Run docker exec the first time, and configure the function for `trap`:

```
$ docker exec -it example /bin/bash
root@ecfc612fe6b8:/# set_workdir_on_exit() { echo "export OLDPWD=$PWD" >> $HOME/.bashrc ;}
root@ecfc612fe6b8:/# trap 'set_workdir_on_exit' EXIT
root@ecfc612fe6b8:/# cd /home
root@ecfc612fe6b8:/home# exit
```

Run docker exec the second time:

```
$ docker exec -it example /bin/bash
root@6a491ad1aee5:/# cd -
/home
root@6a491ad1aee5:/home#
```